# How to Update the cellimages from another function?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a chat application in which I want to show both online members and offline members. Now I'm adding a green dot for online members as cell images like this:

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
[cell.imageView setTag:102];
//NSStringEncoding encoding=NSASCIIStringEncoding;
cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,13,13);
cell.imageView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,0,13,13);
[cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

And now when the user turns offline I want to change this image to red. Now I'm deleting the users who are offline from the table view like this inside that triggering function:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[channel.memberIDs indexOfObject:memberID] inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

But now I don't want to do the delete process. I want to change the image to `red.png` which I'm having. Can anybody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: did you try with [self.tableView reloadData];?

Comment: try to strore the image name in one string. and give it to the image.Every time you are reloading the table that image name wil be restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *cellArray = (NSArray *) [[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[channel.memberIDs indexOfObject:memberID] inSection:0]] ];

    for (int i = 0 ;i < [cellArray count] ;i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [cellArray objectAtIndex:i];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [ self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"]; //image changed to red
        cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

    }

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This code shall change an array of cells image to red image.For a single cell image to change(i.e if array of cells is not desired),remove the for loop and change
   `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [cellArray objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved as follows:

1. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check whether user is online or offline and based on that assign  image to imageView.
2. When any user goes offline just reload your table view using `[yourTableView reloadData];`

Comment: i have a methode which is checking the user is online or not.that methode is triggered when the user goes offline.with in that methode i had done the deleterow methode.but there i want to update the cell image thats i am asking?